# What's the Placeholder field used for in a Rendering?

Tags: presentation

Within View Renderings and Controller Renderings (at least) there is a shared field within the Data section called Placeholder.  What exactly is that field used for?

[image: View Rendering fields]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is a default, used when no placeholder key is given upon inserting the rendering onto the page. This can happen both when editing via Content Editor/Presentation Details or as a result of a Conditional Rendering action.

> ## The Placeholder Rendering Property
>
> The Placeholder rendering property in the Data section of a rendering definition item specifies the
> default placeholder key for the rendering. Sitecore uses the
> Placeholder rendering property as the placeholder key if a user does
> not specify a placeholder key in layout details or if a developer does
> not specify a placeholder key when adding the rendering to layout
> details at runtime using conditional rendering.

Source: [Presentation Component Reference](https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/64/presentation_component_reference-a4.pdf)

Comment: Yes agree with Mark Cassidy, if you don't want to give placeholder name again and again when setting Presentations on different template's standard values, then you can directly define placeholder key here. One more important thing is that priority will be high for Item level presentation's placeholder key rather than Rendering level placeholder key.